# Remove Duplicates in array php

Tags: php, arrays

I like to remove the duplicates in the array. In the below array, I like to remove the duplicate STRIP in array(500).

```
Array
(
    [125] => Array
        (
            [0] => STRIP
        )

    [250] => Array
        (
            [0] => STRIP
        )

    [333] => Array
        (
            [0] => STRIP
        )

    [500] => Array
        (
            [0] => STRIP
            [1] => STRIP
        )

    [] => Array
        (
            [0] => BOTTLE
            [1] => STRIP
        )

)
```

My Expected output will be

```
Array
(
    [125] => Array
        (
            [0] => STRIP
        )
```

`[250] => Array
    (
        [0] => STRIP
    )

[333] => Array
    (
        [0] => STRIP
    )

[500] => Array
    (
        [0] => STRIP
    )

[] => Array
    (
        [0] => BOTTLE
        [1] => STRIP
    )

)`

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post your attempts too?

Comment: A simple call to `array_map('array_unique', $input);` should do the trick. Read more about [`array_map()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_unique()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

Comment: array_map("array_unique", $array) is working fine. thanks axiac

Comment: "": {
        "0": "CAPSULE",
        "2": "MEDICINAL OILS"
      } how i can remove 0,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
array_map("array_unique", $array);
```

---

For more information on `array_map()` you can visit [PHP's Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

Comment: Why should the OP use this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
<?php 
    foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
        $newArray[$k]=array_unique($v);
    }
    print_r($newArray);
?>
```

Comment: You have some syntax errors that will cause this to fail. Please do not use answers to ask questions.

Comment: Thanks Axiac, Now its coming properly. Thanks For your help

Comment: `E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Use of undefined constant newArray - assumed 'newArray'` on `print_r(newArray);` (missing `$`)

Comment: Is not that index? or it is associative massive and "250,500" are keys? in that case I have modified my answer

Comment: For a single array the output was like this        "": {
        "0": "CAPSULE",
        "2": "MEDICINAL OILS"
      }   -- how can i remove 0 and 2

Answer (score 1):

```
 $newArray = array();

 foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
       $newArray[$k]=array_values(array_unique($v));
    }
    print_r($newArray);
```